# Can't apply function to Astropy Bootstrap

Tags: python, astropy

I am having problem when applying a function to the `bootstrap` method inside `astropy.stats` library. Here comes a minimal example:

```
x = np.random.random(10)

f = lambda x: x**2

bootstrap(x, bootfunc=f)
```

And the error is:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-129-0fc2f5a721b2> in <module>()
      3 f = lambda x: x**2
      4 
----> 5 bootstrap(x, bootfunc=f)

/home/gbra/anaconda/envs/astroml/lib/python3.5/site-packages/astropy/stats/funcs.py in bootstrap(data, bootnum, samples, bootfunc)
    956             boot[i] = data[bootarr]
    957         else:
--> 958             boot[i] = bootfunc(data[bootarr])
    959 
    960     return boot

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

If I replace `f` by `numpy.mean` works.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I don't know how bootstrap resampling is supposed to work so I'll wait for someone more knowledgeable to come along and explain it. But this exception is from Numpy and means something is trying to assign an array into a zero-dimensional scalar value in an array. And indeed looking at the source it doesn't handle 1-D inputs properly. So that's probably a bug (even if it's not supposed to take 1-D inputs it should be raising a more useful exception and be better documented).

Comment: Though I also see that bootfunc should be "a function to reduce sampled data" which implies it should reduce the data down to a scalar value (in which case my comment about number of dimensions is irrelevant). Maybe you meant to use a sum of squares instead? The function could still use better error handling in this case though.

Comment: Thanks for your time @Iguananaut. I am trying do a linear regression for each new sample that bootstrap create. I can do this without using the `bootfunc` argument, but I thought that using it would be more straightforward.